# Negative margin "hovering" div goes under later elements

Tags: html, css, hover, z-index, margin

OK, so I have three `<ul>` tags that each have `float: left;` applied to them. The `<li>` tags have a `:hover` specification that causes them to increase in width and gain a negative margin equal to the gain in width, so that on hover they increase in size without moving anything.

The issue is that instead of extending out over the following floated `<ul>` tags, they extend "under" them. Setting `z-index` has not seemed to do anything about this, though I may perhaps be using it wrong. I've tried setting `z-index: 5;` on the `:hover` specification, and I also tried setting `z-index: 3;`, `z-index: 2;`, and `z-index: 1;` on the successive `<ul>` tags, but neither made any difference.

One thing that *did* work was to have the `<ul>` tags be `float: right;` so that the last one was actually left-most, but I don't like this solution as it means my code is in the opposite order as it appears on the page, and it will mean that I have to set manual `tabindex` attributes on everything to fix the tab order.

EDIT: Fixed it; can't answer my own question for 7 hours, but it turns out that `z-index` does not work on `position: static;` (the default) elements. I just added `position: relative;` to the `<li>` tags and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use z-index for static elements. Consider changing their positioning to either `relative` or `absolute`.